# MyLocationOverlay - works in all countries?

Tags: android

On android, we have the MyLocationOverlay class. Does this class have any issues when the device owner is in certain countries? I don't have any reason to believe it would not work, just not sure with google TOS - maybe android devices sold in some countries don't have support for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you by experience, that it does have some issues in China. Locations here are displayed off by around 100 meters (even more). Funnily, latest version of Google maps dealt with it and positions are now accurate. To the best of my knowledge this offset function is not linear. MyLocationOverlay works well though, as it displays the position given by the "infrastructure".